# Deleting master node from existing Redis Cluster

Tags: redis

I want to delete a master node from existing Redis Cluster. I tried following the instructions from http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial but unable to follow. Help??

Comment: To delete a master node it has to be empty, so you have to move the data slots to the other nodes. is that happening ?

Comment: Rabee AbdelWahab - As I am new to Redis, moving the data slots to the other nodes means resharding rite??? Anyhow, when I try deleting the node, it gives me an error that either node is connected to other node or has some keys in database 0.

Answer (score 2):

As per previous answer, to delete a master node it must be empty. That means we've to [flushall](https://redis.io/commands/flushall) the data or migrate hash slot to another existing master.

But as [redis reconfiguration](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#cluster-live-reconfiguration) and [redis cluster resharding](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-setslot#redis-cluster-live-resharding-explained) says, additional steps may need to be added after step 5 in the previous answer.

A solution that works for me is as following according to redis official docs. The order is important here.

We'll call the node that has the current ownership of the hash slot the **source node**, and the node where we want to migrate the **destination node**.

For each slot:

1. Send `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> IMPORTING <source-node-id>` to **destination node** to set the **slot** to **importing** state.
2. Send `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> MIGRATING <destination-node-id>` to **source node** to set the **slot** to **migrating** state.
3. Get keys from the **source node** with [CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-getkeysinslot) command and move them into the **destination node** using the following [MIGRATE](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) command.

   `MIGRATE target_host target_port key target_database_id timeout`

   In Redis Cluster there is no need to specify a database other than 0, but [MIGRATE](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) is a general command that can be used for other tasks not involving Redis Cluster.
4. When the migration process is finally finished, use `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> NODE <destination-node-id>` in both **source node** and **destination node** in order to set the slot to their normal state again. The same command is usually sent to all other nodes to avoid waiting for the natural propagation of the new configuration across the cluster.

A simple example bash script to do this is also given here:

source-ip: `172.17.0.5`. source-id: `1f70a5107e0042a7d33a9efaf88dbdfecd78076a`

destination-ip: `172.17.0.4`. destination-id: `7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02`

another master ip: `172.17.0.7`

```
for i in `seq 0 5460`; do
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.4 cluster setslot ${i} importing 1f70a5107e0042a7d33a9efaf88dbdfecd78076a
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.5 cluster setslot ${i} migrating 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
    while true; do
        key=`redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.5 cluster getkeysinslot ${i} 1`
        if [ "" = "$key" ]; then
            echo "there are no key in this slot ${i}"
            break
        fi
        redis-cli -h 172.17.0.5 migrate 172.17.0.4 6379 ${key} 0 5000
    done
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.5 cluster setslot ${i} node 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.4 cluster setslot ${i} node 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.7 cluster setslot ${i} node 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Node should be empty before deleting it. As such, we need to move the data and also slots before deleting a node.

Follow below steps to migrate:

1. Connect to destination node:
2. cluster `setslot` (slot no) importing (source node id)

Connect to source node:

3. cluster `setslot` (slot no) migrating (destination node id)
4. migrate (destination ip) (destination port) key  (destination db) (timeout)

Connect to destination node:

5. cluster `setslot` (slot no) node (dest node)

We can do the above in a loop for all the slots and keys and then delete the source node.